# Entity Framework 6 - How to mark a property as NOT foreign key

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm using ASP.NET MVC5 together with EF6 and using the code first approach.

I have a property in a model that i need to to tell EF6 is NOT a foreign key:

```
public class LogEntry
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int LogDayID { get; set; }
    public int LogEntryTypeID { get; set; }
    public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
    public DateTime Clock { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }

    public virtual LogDay LogDay { get; set; }
    public virtual LogEntryType LogEntryType { get; set; }
    public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
}

[NotMapped]
public class Department
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

The model Department has the [NotMapped] as this model should not be stored in the database.

I thought this was enough to make EF6 realise that DepartmentID in LogEntry shouldn't be a foreign key.. But instead it throws me an error that 'Department' is not mapped.

EDIT: Even if i remove the DepartmentID from LogEntry it still complains with the above error.

Here's the complete error message:

> "The type 'SupervisorLogWeb.Models.Department' was not mapped. Check that the type has not been explicitly excluded by using the Ignore method or NotMappedAttribute data annotation. Verify that the type was defined as a class, is not primitive or generic, and does not inherit from EntityObject."

Comment: Is Department part of your DBContext? If yes - that's not okay here.

Comment: T.Glatzer - That was it! I completely forgot to remove them from the DbContext. Thanks. How can i mark this as the solution?

Comment: I wrote it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently your ComplexType is discovered as a Entity - this happens, if you decided to refactor an former Entity to a ComplexType.

The ModelBuilder will decide if an type is an Entity or not (more or less) by it's presence or absence in the DbContext.

So check if your class is still defined as DbSet inside the Context and adjust accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Add the [NotMapped](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.notmappedattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) attribute to the `DeparmentID` property as well. This attribute can also be applied on properties.

When all your mappings are based on conventions, EF (or any tool) can't really tell whether you broke the convention intentionally or you made a mistake. It can apply some heuristics but it's better to fail and ask the programmer than implement an unwanted mapping.

Comment: But that would make it not store DepartmentID in the database which it should. Please also see my edit in my original post. I get the error even if i remove DepartmentID so the problem lies somewhere else.

Comment: You still have a `Department` property in your DTO, which I didn't notice earlier.

Comment: If you mean the virtual Department object - then it needs to be there. The underlying data for the Department object comes from sharepoint while the DepartmentID should be stored in the database.

Comment: Have you tried putting the NotMapped attribute there?